# How to transfer files betwen 2 hosting servers?

Tags: ftp, vps, web-hosting, migration, file-transfer

I have a live website that I want to change my hosting provider to a new hosting company. Currently I have several gigabytes of data as a .zip files in my old hosting environment that I want to shift to the new host.
So is there any way to transfer these files between  the 2 servers (my old hosting to my new hosting) online without re-uploading it from my PC?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on what access you have to your current VPS. If you have command line access and can use FTP then you can use FTP to transfer the zip file to your new VPS.

EDIT:

FTP & SFTP have similar command sets so

use your remote vps username and password when asked

```
cd /to/the/directory/with/the/zipfile

sftp yournewhost.tld
User <your username>
Password: <your password>
sftp> put zipfile.zip
sftp> quit
```

At every point above you can substitute `ftp` for `sftp` if you want.

Comment: i thing i have full access to my VPS and i can use SSH, but relay i don't have a good knowledge with that, so can you please give me any tutorial link or how to do that exactly

Comment: I've added some notes on how to do it.

Comment: or just "scp filename.zip username@hostname:~/".  It'll prompt for a password.

Answer (score 1):

If your host provides shell access, you can telnet/ssh into your old host, then ftp/sftp into your new host and transfer the files that way. That wouldn't require you to download to your PC then re-upload.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest [Globus Online](https://www.globusonline.org) to do the file transfer if your transferring several gigabytes of information as Globus allows you to set up the file transfer and forget about it, while it handles things like file checking and automatically retransmitting files if errors are detected.